# How to create an associative array with the same keys by having two normal arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have read countless posts on stackoverflow but I was unable to solve my problem.

I have two arrays:

```
arr_name = ["alice", "igor", "prince"]
arr_slug = ["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"]
```

I want the result to be this:

```
      var data = {
        "tag_info": [
          "name":"alice",
          "slug":"link_1"
        ],
        "tag_info": [
          "name":"igor",
          "slug":"link_2"
        ],
        "tag_info": [
          "name":"prince",
          "slug":"link_3"
        ],
      };
```

I insert my code snippet since I was wrong not to
put it before.
This is what I was trying to do:

```
      arr_name = ["alice", "igor", "prince"]
      arr_slug = ["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"]
      new_name = []
      new_slug = []

      arr_name.forEach(function(property) {
        new_name.push({"name":property});
      });
      arr_slug.forEach(function(property2) {
        new_slug.push({"slug":property2});
      });
      var data = {'tags_info':{new_name,new_slug}};
```

The result I get is the following:

```
      "tag_info" : {
        "new_name" : [{
          "name":"alice",
          "name":"igor",
          "name":"prince"
        ]},
        "new_slug" : {[
          "slug":"link_1"
          "slug":"link_2"
          "slug":"link_3"
        ]}
      }
```

I can't build the right loop
How should I do it?

Comment: your desired output isn't possible. Objects need unique keys and arrays cannot have key-value pairs within them

Comment: Post the JavaScript as a [mcve], you've must tried something...

Comment: You need to define a meaningful result first. Your current expectation is a syntax error in itself, as @NickParsons describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm this introduces some consistancy concerns, since you don't have any kind of key to correlate values, but if you're 100% sure you will always have two arrays of the same length and each position of one relates to the some position of the other, then you can use this:

```
let arr_name = ["alice", "igor", "prince"]
let arr_slug = ["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"]

let result = arr_name.reduce((data, name, index) => {
  data.push( {
    'tag_info': {
      name: name,
      slug: arr_slug[index]
    }
  })
  return data;

}, []);
```

Have in mind this won't result in the structure you showed, because it's impossible, as stated by @Nick Parsons, since it's an invalid JSON

Comment: why not `return data.concat({})`

Comment: concat returns a new array, containing all the elements of the concatenated arrays. In this case, the output is an array containing a single object with two properties each, name and slug

Comment: I inserted an example of what I was trying to do, obviously it was wrong. This was what I was trying to achieve, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Objects can't have multiple keys with the same name. They need to be unique.

What you can instead have is an array of objects.

Assuming both your arrays have the same length and their corresponding elements are always in the same index, you can do this:

```js
let arr_name = [ "alice", "bob" ];
let arr_slug = [ "link_1", "link_2" ];

let data = arr_name.map((name, index) => ({
    name,
    slug: arr_slug[index],
}));
```

And the value of `data` will be:

```js
[
    { name: "alice", slug: "link_1" },
    { name: "bob", slug: "link_2" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I was looking for is exactly like @Jorge Solis did